# Usando v-bind ou v-model para atualizar um input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Estou utilizando o Vue.js em um projeto e gostaria da ajuda de vocês.
Vou tentar exemplificar o que estou fazendo.

Eu tenho 2 botoes, + e - , quando o usuário clicar em ou no outro quero que atualize o meu input com os valores (incremento ou decremento).

A questão é que não estou conseguindo atualizar o meu input automatico, estarei colocando abaixo o meu código completo.

```
<section class="offer-dedicated-nav bg-white border-top-0 shadow-sm">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">            
            <ul class="nav" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-order-online-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-order-online" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-order-online" aria-selected="true">Cardápio Digital</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="pills-gallery-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-gallery" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-gallery" aria-selected="false">Galeria de Fotos</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="pills-restaurant-info-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-restaurant-info" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-restaurant-info" aria-selected="false">Informações</a>
               </li>               
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="pills-reviews-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-reviews" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-reviews" aria-selected="false">Comentários</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
<section class="offer-dedicated-body pt-2 pb-2 mt-4 mb-4">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="offer-dedicated-body-left">
               <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade show active cardapio" id="pills-order-online" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-order-online-tab">
                     {% verbatim %}
                     <div id="#menu" class="bg-white rounded shadow-sm p-4 mb-4 explore-outlets">
                        <h5 class="mb-4">{{ title }}</h5>
                        <div class="explore-outlets-search mb-4">
                           <div class="input-group">
                              <input type="text" 
                              placeholder="Com o que você quer refrescar hoje?" 
                              v-on:input="updateFilter"
                              class="form-control">
                              <div class="input-group-append">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                                 <i class="icofont-search"></i>
                                 </button>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class="mb-3"></h6>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4" 
                              v-for="(product, index) in products"
                              v-if="!search || product.name_lower.indexOf(search) !== -1">
                              <div class="list-card bg-white h-100 rounded overflow-hidden position-relative shadow-sm">
                                 <div class="list-card-image">
                                    <div class="star position-absolute">
                                          <span class="badge badge-success">
                                             <i class="icofont-star"></i> THE BEST</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="favourite-heart text-danger position-absolute">
                                       <a href="#"><i class="icofont-heart"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="member-plan position-absolute">
                                       <span class="badge badge-dark">+ VENDIDO</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" v-if="product.images.length">
                                       <img v-bind:src="product.images[0]" class="img-fluid item-img">
                                    </a>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="p-3 position-relative">
                                    <div class="list-card-body">
                                       <h6 class="mb-1"><a href="#" class="text-black">{{ product.name }}</a></h6>
                                       <p class="text-gray time mb-0"><a class="btn btn-link btn-sm pl-0 text-black pr-0" href="#">R$ {{ product.price|money }} </a>
                                          <span class="float-right"> 
                                             <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" @click="addItemSelected(index)" href="javascript:;">ADD</a>
                                          </span>
                                       </p>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>                           
                        </div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="row" v-if="productPrepareOrder">                       
                        <h5 class="mb-4 mt-3 col-md-12">0<small class="h6 text-black-50"> Adicionais Selecionados</small></h5>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                           <div class="bg-white rounded border shadow-sm mb-4">
                              <div class="gold-members p-3 border-bottom">
                                 <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm  float-right" href="#">ADICIONAR NO CARRINHO</a>
                                 <div class="media">
                                    <div class="mr-3"><i class="icofont-ui-press text-warning food-item"></i></div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                       <h6 class="mb-1">{{ productPrepareOrder.name }}</h6>
                                       <p class="text-gray mb-0">R$ {{ productPrepareOrder.price|money }} </p>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="gold-members p-3 border-bottom" v-for="(additional, index) in productPrepareOrder.additionals">
                                 <span class="count-number float-right">
                                 <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary  btn-sm left dec">
                                    <i class="icofont-minus"></i>
                                 </button>

                                 <input v-bind:id="'additional-'+additional.id" v-model="productPreAddOrder.additionals[(additional.id)].amount" class="count-number-input" type="text" readonly="true">

                                 <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm right inc" @click="addAdditionalItem(additional.id)"> 
                                    <i class="icofont-plus"></i>
                                 </button>
                                 </span>
                                 <div class="media">
                                    <div class="mr-3"><i class="icofont-ui-press text-danger food-item"></i></div>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                       <h6 class="mb-1">{{ additional.name }} 
                                          <!-- <span class="badge badge-success">Mais utilizado</span> -->
                                       </h6>
                                       <p class="text-gray mb-0">R$ {{ additional.price|money }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>                             
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     {% endverbatim %}
                  </div>
                  <!-- /cardapio -->

               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

      </div>
   </div>
</section>
{% put scripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">


   Vue.filter('money', function (value) {
     let val = (value/1).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')
     return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
   });

   Vue.filter('existsProperty', function (value) {
     console.log(value);
   });

   var menu = new Vue({
      el: '.cardapio',      
      data () {
         return {
            search: '',
            title: 'Cardápio digital',
            products: null,
            productPrepareOrder: null,
            productPreAddOrder: {},
         }
      },      
      methods: {
         loadListProducts: function(){
            var self = this;
            $.request("onListProducts", {
               success: function(data) {
                  self.products = data.products;  
               },
            });
         },
         updateFilter: function(event){              
            this.search = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
         },
         addItemSelected: function(index){
            var self = this;
            self.productPrepareOrder = self.products[index];
            self.productPreAddOrder = {
               id: self.productPrepareOrder.id,
               name: self.productPrepareOrder.name,
               price: self.productPrepareOrder.price,
               additionals: {
               }
            }

            self.productPrepareOrder.additionals.forEach(function(obj,value){
               self.productPreAddOrder.additionals[obj.id] = {
                  id: obj.id,
                  name: obj.name,
                  amount: 0,
                  price: obj.price,
                  price_total: 0,
               };
            });

            console.log(self.productPreAddOrder)
         },
         addAdditionalItem: function(index){            
            var self = this;
            var amount = self.productPreAddOrder.additionals[index].amount;            
            amount = amount + 1;
            self.productPreAddOrder.additionals[index].amount = amount;
            console.log(self.productPreAddOrder.additionals);
         }
      },     
      mounted () {
         this.loadListProducts();
      }
   });
</script>
{% endput %}
```

A função addAdditionalItem tecnicamente atualiza a variavel amount. Porém não é refletido no value do input.

--- EDIT ---
O trecho que faz o que citei acima são esses:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary  btn-sm left dec">
                                    <i class="icofont-minus"></i>
                                 </button>

                                 <input v-bind:id="'additional-'+additional.id" v-model="productPreAddOrder.additionals[(additional.id)].amount" class="count-number-input" type="text" readonly="true">

                                 <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm right inc" @click="addAdditionalItem(additional.id)"> 
                                    <i class="icofont-plus"></i>
                                 </button>
```

Comment: Tenta colocar só o necessário para reproduzir o erro, do modo como está fica complicado te ajudar

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza obrigado pelo seu comentário. Adicionei no post principal apenas a parte do HTML que possui as acoes que citei no post.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
Cria uma propriedade para cada input no data e seta ela como v-model do input e no click do button chama uma function que vai incrementar ou decrementar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]